# Is it possible to give a bootstrap btn a 5 point?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I'm looking to make a bootstrap btn look a little differently with there being a 5 point at the bottom of its base. I know its possible to do shapes this way using the :before and :after tools and transform but I want to put text inside of them which is why I'm having so much trouble. Is it possible to deal directly with the btn class to make this effect happen?[image]

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service so have a go and we're more than willing to help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SkewY` as shown in the demo below:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px solid green;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% + 10px);
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
div:before {
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  left: -10px;
}
div:after {
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Request a Quote</div>
```

Comment: Thank you jbutler. I was using SkewY but I wasn't able to reproduce the shape. The width calc is something new I didn't realize I could do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

gradient can be a first chip approach ...

example in situation: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wGEyvd

```css
button {
  color:green;
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  margin:1em auto;
  padding:1.5em 0 2.5em;
  border:none;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, green, green) top,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, green,green) top left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, green,green) top right,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 45%, green 47%, green 51%, transparent 52%) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 45%, green 47%, green 51%, transparent 52%) bottom right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 3px, 3px 70%, 3px 70%,50% 30%, 50% 30%;
}
```

```html
<button>REQUEST A CODE</button>
```